# Fast retrieval of info with a fixed structure from a list of web links

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, automation, webpage

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains a list of web links (all to the same website, but different pages). All of these pages have the same layout/structure, and I want to retrieve the same piece of info (different values on different pages) from every page/link.

Obviously I can click on each link in a cell, go to the page, and note down the info manually. However, there are hundreds of them and I see it as something that can be automated. 
How can I approach this?

Comment: Asking for software or a plug-in will get the question closed because that's off-topic.  Asking someone to write you a script would likely be closed as too broad.  So just ask how to accomplish the task.  Which brings us to the next issue.  Your description is pretty nebulous, and the target could be any type of anything.  Add an example or two of exactly what you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: barlop’s approach will probably work.   If you want something more Excel-focused, look into VBA.  As fixer1234 says, we won’t write it for you.  If you want to pursue this approach, go learn VBA (there are lots of resources on the Internet and in Excel itself; also, search [SU]) and try to solve the problem yourself.  If you get something working, but you run into trouble, then you can come back to us with specifics.

Comment: @fixer1234 it is not that nebulous. I was able to answer it. And if a person is able to generalise their question while still getting an answer then that's actually better (and also shows a good problem solving mindset). Likewise if an answer works for more than just a specific case, that's better.

Comment: @fixer1234 and if it just a tiny bit that you thought was a bit nebulous like just half of one of his sentences that was a bit nebulous then you should quote that and state why, rather than claiming his post is nebulous.

Comment: @barlop, I read this as an Excel problem. Kudos for looking at this bigger picture. It looks like your answer solved the problem for the OP. To me, the entire question seemed too broad and ambiguous, and really still does, even though you were able to get the OP to a solution.  I reread your answer and it looks like an actual solution, so +1.  And I guess that proves that the question isn't necessarily too ambiguous, so I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can copy/paste them from excel into notepad that can easily save as plain text. If you get one link per line then save that file as e.g. blah.a  and download wget  then it's no longer an excel thing.

so now say you have produced a file of links then you can use a command called wget (which you'd have to download and has nothing to do with excel).  So let's say each line of the file has a line like http://blah.com/abc.html   So then you do  wget -i blah.a   and then it will download each link there.. but you should also include a delay so it doesn't bog down the server so `wget -i blah.a`  but with something like -t   -T  and -w..  e.g.  `-t 1 -T 5 -w 1` (retries, timeout and wait respectively), so setting things like retry and timeout and wait.  So `wget -t 1 -T 5 -w 1 -i blah.a<ENTER>` Obviously this is in wget --help. (with even more detail in the wget manual that is online).   You can get wget with e.g. cygwin.